# textarea label vertical-align: middle

Tags: html, css, textarea, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the label for this text area in the middle of the text box, but it just isn't working. The output looks something like this:

```
          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      
          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
Synopsis: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here's the code I've been trying. TY!

```
<style>
label textarea{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<label>Synopsis: <textarea style="border: none" rows="7" cols="60">$v_Synopsis</textarea></label>
```

Comment: Why is the input inside the label?

Comment: `<textarea>` goes after `</label>`. Next, jsfiddle your code.

Comment: @Paulie_D When a control is inside a `<label>`, the label is associated with the control. You can also use the explicit `for` attribute.

Answer (score 18):

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gedml)

HTML

```
 <div>
  <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label,
textarea{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;

}
```

Comment: however when I add back in style="border: none" for the textarea the label goes back to it's original spot. Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Perhaps a you could make JSfiddle to demonstrate your issue as removing the border (probably poor UX) makes no difference in the Codepen example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rC5nj/ Not sure if I did that right first time using JSfiddle.

it shows the output of the label on top of the text box, the real output is on the left side on the last line. 

I'm trying to get it on the  left side middle.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/pG4KA/1/ You forgot the `inline-block`. The border removal doesn't shrink the textarea...it just looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. 
First the textarea is floated right, then the word "address" appears before it.
It's in reverse order, but displays correctly

```
<p>
<span style="float:right;"><textarea rows="3" cols="32" name="Add"></textarea></span>
<span style="float:right;">Address</span>
</p>
```

To show:

```
Address┌──────────────┐
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
label { display:inline-block; vertical-align:central; }

textarea { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Answer (score -1):

you forgot : ","

```
    <style>
label, textarea{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<label>Synopsis: </label> <textarea style="border: 1" rows="3" cols="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: I know what was wrong all along, I needed to auto resize the text box using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

This will always work and you have the flexibility of placing the label at either; top, middle or bottom

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <label for="mytextarea">My Label</label>
    <textarea name="mytextarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv{
    display: table-cell;
}

label, textarea{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /** Can be switched to 'top' if you so wish **/
}
```