# VueJs Form textarea and text formatting issue using BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using BootstrapVue to build a row with two columns. The first column has a text and the second column has a [`b-form-textarea`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-textarea). I also want a text (`"data"`) to appear **next** to the text-area. But the text only shows up below the text-area. I think it is because of some css property of `b-form-textarea`.

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lbharwc/7/)

However, when using a plain `textarea`, the text appears next to it (refer fiddle/screenshot below).

I would like to have the text not only next to the text-area but centered vertically w.r.t to the textarea side.

**NOTE:** When viewing in fiddle based on your screen width, both the text might appear at the bottom. Pasting a screenshot to avoid confusion.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use [`vue-bootstrap layouts`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout) to align your elements like:

```
  <div class="col-4">
        <b-row align-v="center" >
        <b-col cols="10">
          <b-form-textarea></b-form-textarea>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="2"> <span> data </span></b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This made the text appear as expected. But, I'm not able to get the text vertically aligned/centered. [Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/gks8et7j/). I'm trying something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522921/4405757). So, even if the text-area is dragged/expanded, the text would be to the center right of it

Comment: try to add `align-v` prop as follows : `<b-row align-v="center" >`